# Wlox- open source crypto currency exchange is not working

Tags: php, cryptography, exchange-server, currency, bitcoin

Hi i tried to setup an wlox -open source crpto- currency exchange from the link , https://github.com/wlox/wlox. but the contents on home banner and the bitcoin values are not populating at home page. The server link that I installed wlox is http://crypto.beeone.co.uk/wlox/frontend/htdocs/. Let me know the reason?

Comment: It's really hard to help you when you don't provide any information about what you have done, and what problems you have other than "not working".

Comment: the problem is in the site http://crypto.beeone.co.uk/wlox/frontend/htdocs/. not showing the bitcoin market values. . Please check the site https://1btcxe.com/. I tried like this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your database settings are okay, the following may help:

- Make sure your folder permissions are set to 755. You can use Bitvise for ssh login and run the following command: sudo chmod -R 755 .
- Ensure your settings in backstage2 are correct.